# Thresholds as function of treatment

Tags: treatment-effect

Y=function of some treatment. So when a treatment is applied I want to develop thresholds(depending on some sort of variance). Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Your question is neither well defined nor explained. Please elaborate a bit more on what you want to know, perhaps providing data, an example or something that's illustrative of your concerns.